# Subject question vs. object question

Tags: questions, subjects, objects

In the text book that I am supposed to use in my lessons I have this explanation on the difference between subject and object questions:

[image]

I want you to especially pay attention to this sentence above:

> "*In subject questions ...  we don't normally use an auxiliary verb in
> the Present or Past simple*"

Then, right on the next page I have this exercise:

[image]

I this task, as far as I understand, students are asked to come up with two questions for each sentence and one question must be an object question and the other one must be a subject one.

However, when I look at the sentence 3 there:

[image: 3.]

it looks to me like both suggested questions are object questions:

"What did Eva do yesterday?"

"How many films did Eva watch?"

At least, in both of these questions the auxiliary verb "did" is used, which, according to what is written above ("*In subject questions ...  we don't normally use an auxiliary verb*"), means that none of them is a subject question.

Can anyone, please, explain to me my confusion?

Comment: Because most if not all of the other questions seem to be looking for a straightforward ***noun*** as the answer, they might be looking for *What did Eva **watch** yesterday?,* or feasibly *Eva **watched what** yesterday?* (Answer: ***three films***, not the verb-based element ***watched** three films*). But #3 is a bad example anyway, as you've obviously discovered yourself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don't think they are looking for "_What did Eva watch yesterday?_" because there is "_do_" right after the blank: "_What____________ do yesterday?_" Besides, isn't  _What did Eva watch yesterday?_ still a subject question?

Comment: Well, like I said, it's a rubbish test anyway, so it doesn't really matter what the setter was thinking. But *What did Eva watch yesterday?* is an "object" question, as you suggested in the question (not a "subject" question as in your comment).

Comment: ...not sure how *What was watched by Eva?* plays out there, though. It's an awkward passive, but ***Three films** were watched by Eva* looks like a "subject" response to me. I'm just not sure how answering any of these questions helps anyone learn English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I see. Thank you for this confirmation. "_is an "object" question, as you suggested in the question (not a "subject" question as in your comment)_" - Sorry. This was a typo by me in the comment.

Comment: Please don't use images in your question, at least not without the complete text in the image description. People who use screen readers can't read the content of an image, and somebody searching for terms in your image won't find this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "subject question" would be  "Who watched three films yesterday?"

There are several different predicate questions that could be asked, depending on the "gap".

> How many films did Eva watch  (gapping "three")
>
> What did Eva watch yesterday (gapping "three films")
>
> What did Eva watch three of, yesterday (gapping "films")
>
> What did Eva do yesterday, (gapping "watch three films)
>
> When did Eva watch three films (gapping "yesterday)

Those would all show "object question"  type grammar.

Comment: +1 In other words, your book is wrong.

Comment: @gotube - Are you saying this to James or to me?

Comment: To you, @brilliant. James explained why the book is wrong, but didn't come right out and say it.

Comment: @gotube - Got it. Thank you!